# Show file name in delete prompt?

Tags: spacemacs, warning, prompt

When I delete the current buffer's file (in spacemacs via `SPC f D`, a prompt shows up in the minibuffer:

> Are you sure you want to delete this file? (y or n)

I would find it safer if that warning displayed the file name / path:

> Are you sure you want to delete /path/to/current/buffers/file ? (y or n)

What I do now is check whether the focus is really on the buffer of the file I want to delete but the prompt could allow another way of double checking.

How could one achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are suggesting an enhancement to Spacemacs. Maybe report that suggestion to the Spacemacs maintainers? Your question itself is unclear (to me): how could one achieve what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `spacemacs/delete-current-buffer-file` is defined in [spacemacs-base/funcs.el](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/582f9aa45c2c90bc6ec98bccda33fc428e4c6d48/layers/%2Bdistributions/spacemacs-base/funcs.el#L349-L363).

You can override it with the desired function. Note that I just changed the prompt of the `yes-or-no-p` question.

```el
(defun my-spacemacs/delete-current-buffer-file ()
  "Removes file connected to current buffer and kills buffer."
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name))
        (buffer (current-buffer))
        (name (buffer-name)))
    (if (not (and filename (file-exists-p filename)))
        (ido-kill-buffer)
      (when (yes-or-no-p (format "Are you sure you want to delete %S? " filename))
        (delete-file filename t)
        (kill-buffer buffer)
        (when (and (configuration-layer/package-usedp 'projectile)
                   (projectile-project-p))
          (call-interactively #'projectile-invalidate-cache))
        (message "File '%s' successfully removed" filename)))))

(advice-add 'spacemacs/delete-current-buffer-file :override #'my-spacemacs/delete-current-buffer-file)
```

DISCLAIMER: I don't use spacemacs. The lisp code is currently untested. You need to test it for yourself.

Note further that there is also the very similar function [`spacemacs\delete-file`](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/582f9aa45c2c90bc6ec98bccda33fc428e4c6d48/layers/%2Bdistributions/spacemacs-base/funcs.el#L321). You can adopt the same changes to that function if you like.

As Drew suggested you should add an [enhancement issue at the spacemacs project page](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/new).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I tested the prompt and deletion and that works. Is the `advice-add` a general way to override functions? The alternative is to define the function in `dotspacemacs/user-config` which will override default spacemacs definitions.

Comment: @user905686 Yes [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) is the way to override functions. It has the advantage that it is reversible. If you need the original behavior you can use `advice-remove`. Furthermore, the original doc-string is retained and the documentation of the advising function is added.